# Deploy Flask Application using python 3.7

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, python-3.7

I follow this guideline to deploy my python application. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-flask.html

I got this bug when use command eb deploy:

```
2021/09/10 17:26:49.653297 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2021/09/10 17:26:49.653315 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2021/09/10 17:26:49.656613 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2021/09/10 17:26:49.657975 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [StageApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: chown /var/app/staging/env/lib/python3.7/collections: no such file or directory

2021/09/10 17:26:49.657984 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/09/10 17:26:49.658080 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1631294809,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

its so annoy because it can not find python 3.7 to run. can anyone give me a hand to by pass this mess?

application.py

```
# app.py

from flask import Flask
application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application.run()
```

requirements.txt

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Comment: That tutorial has you create an eb 3.6 enviro.  Is that what you created?  So there won't be a python3.7 directory.  But ... where did that command come from ... chown on that dir?  That isn't part of this tutorial?  Pls provide output of eb status from your project?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me while following the tutorial as well.

The problem, in my case, was that my virtual environment folder `venv` was getting swept up in the deploy and breaking it.

I thought that I could put the path in `.ebignore` to prevent this, but I did not read the `.ebignore` documentation clearly:

> If .ebignore isn't present, but .gitignore is, the EB CLI ignores files specified in .gitignore. If .ebignore is present, the EB CLI doesn't read .gitignore.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore

In my case, I just removed the `.ebignore` file completely, added a line for `venv` into my `.gitignore` file, ran `eb deploy` again and everything worked.